# Would a diode with a different forward voltage and response time cause this circuit to behave erratically?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, integrated-circuit, schematics, circuit-theory

I accidentally substituted diode [RS1BB-13-F](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ds15002-84557.pdf) for [S1BB-13-F](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ds16003-83672.pdf).

RS1BB-13-F's forward voltage is 1.3V, while S1BB-13-F is 1.1V.

These substitutions were at D8 and D9 in the schematic (top right corner).

LEDs aren't behaving normally and ICs are overheating. Based on the circuit, could the incorrect diode be the culprit? Thanks for your help.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: It's unlikely the diodes are your culprit. They are protection diodes only, and in normal operation should never be forward-biased anyway. And the diode you mistakenly used has better reverse-bias characteristics anyway.

Comment: Did you check your voltages first? Are they +-12V relative to ground, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Those diodes are only forward biased if something goes very wrong. They aren't zeners, and they are intended to protect the ICs from gross reverse voltage is you do something silly like hook up the power supply backwards.

Answer (score 0):

What LEDs and what supply is used?

Most likely your supply is not centre tapped and thus imbalanced so the assumption that V+=12V and V-=-12V is probably false but I suspect you just have a 24V supply.  The caps to not balance the load and the diodes do nothing to regulated the split.

If you are seeing weird problems, this is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

They're unlikely to fully protect the circuit against reverse supply voltage at significant current, so if, if, such an event did occur one might expect some of the chips to have gone pins-up (and perhaps to be overheating). The increased forward drop would not help at all.

Schottky diodes would be a much better choice in that position.